# Adding patterns to addResourceHandler always returned error when want to serve static content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, static-content

I went through all question here, all docs according to `Spring` and couldn't find solution which make my case work. 
The case is that I would like to secure my application (`Spring Boot with Angular 4`) by `Spring Security`. So the first things which I did was to add two `Configuration` classes, ex:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic();
    }

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.inventory")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/", "/#/", "/resources/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/index.html", "/resources/static/index.html", "/resources/static/index.html");
    }
}

@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/#/")
    public String index() {
        return "forward:/resources/static/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

As you see in `Controller` I tried to use to diffrent attempts to serve static content. Unfortunately all this returns:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not resolve view with name 'index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

What am I doing wrong? Why I can't get this static content? Of course my static content is under `resources/static` and there are `.js` files and ex. `index.html`.

Comment: If you are going with angular I'm guessing you need a rest service. Why use @EnableWebMvc?-remove that annotation. Since you are using spring boot you don't have to user a WebMvcConfigurerAdapter - addResourceHandlers - Remove that, also remove your request mapping(value = "/"),(value = "/#/") . Put your indexhtml in the src/java/main/resources/static/ folder and just go to localhost:8080/index.html. Did this work?

Comment: @jdc91 - ok it works in a way that I see all the static content. But when I run the app first what it displayed to me is a `Spring Security` form login - but I have created my own - `Angular 4 form login` which is not shown first - do you know why? It's not a `jsp` or `thymeleaf` or anything similar - it is a form created in `Angular`. What is more I can go that form login but only when I provide login and password to the `Spring Security` form login as I said before - it's strange, isn't it? Secondly whenever I get to that `Angular` form login and provide credentials it always throw `404` 1/2

Comment: @jdc91 so I have changed my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class `configure` method into:  `@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/static/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }` - and still it doesn't work :( 2/2

Comment: Your default static resource path pattern is /** which is spring boot's in built default setting. So in your application.properties, go and set the property. spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/ui/**. Now your static resources are served via localhost:8080/ui/index.html. Now in your spring security config..... allow this url pattern as ===> http.authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/ui/**").permitAll()